# MTG: Probability of drawing a card with enough mana to play it.

Tags: probability

Consider a 60 card MTG deck containing the following:

- 12 Plains
- 13 Swamp
- 3 Spell Card
- 32 Other cards

Drawing 7 cards initially and an additional card each turn, what is the probability that a player will have at least one Spell Card, at least one Plain and at least two Swamps in their hand by turn three?

I have been trying to solve the problem with a hypergeometric distribution. This works when I need the probability of having at least two Swamps by turn two, but the issue here is combining these multiple scenarios together.

After much effort, I feel like I'm in over over my head. I'm not afraid of math, but I am willing to raise my hand and say I just don't know. This problem seems to be much more complex than I bargained for.

I have actually built a simulator that will approximate the answer via brute force so I will at least know I have the right answer when I see it. However, I am in search of a more pure answer.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: It looks like you need to use the *multivariate hypergeometric* distribution. You will have drawn 10 cards by the third round, and you want at least 1 plain and at least 2 swamps, with the remainder being "other". I guess it doesn't matter whether the lands are in your hand or on the battlefield (since you can't hold all of these cards in your hand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MPW is right, this is a straight [Multivariate hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution)

The player will have drawn 10 cards, the chance of *exactly* 1 spell, 1 plain and 2 swamps in (or having passed through) their hand is

$$P(1Sp,1P,2Sw)=\frac{{3\choose1}{12\choose1}{13\choose2}{32\choose6}}{60\choose10}$$

The chance of *at least* is

$$P(\ge1Sp,\ge1P,\ge2Sw)=\sum_{Sp=1}^3\sum_{P=1}^{8-Sp}\sum_{Sw=2}^{10-P-Sw}\frac{{3\choose Sp}{12\choose P}{13\choose Sw}{32\choose10-Sp-P-Sw}}{60\choose10}$$

Comment: Can you explain how you got the 8-Sp in the second summation series?

Comment: The $Sw$ will take a minimum of 2 from the 10 (hence the 8), the $Sp$ will take $Sp$ leaving a maximum of $8-Sp$ for the $P$.

Comment: Sorry, do you mind expanding your answer a bit? The multiplied summations are throwing me off. Also, I was wondering if the 13 choose Sp is a typo? Should that be 13 choose Sw? (Example 2.9 of http://www.statpower.net/Content/310/Summation%20Algebra.pdf was helpful to understand the mechanics of this operation, but I'm still having trouble seeing how you got there)

Comment: It simply means you have to add up all of the ways that could have at least or more of each type of card. Yes it was a typo. The answer is a shade over 24%.

Comment: Ok great - I wrote a quick forloop and came out with the same answer. Now I'll just need to apply this more generally. Thanks, Dale!

Comment: Still having some issues understanding the upper limits of the summations (eg. 3, 8-SP, 10-P-Sw). Can you explain how you got there? Or perhaps point me to a resource that could explain that process? I feel like a few critical steps are not being shown in the answer.

Comment: The summations are the mathematical equivalent of nested for loops - how did you work out the upper bounds for these?

Comment: Well that's my question. I understand that its the equivalent of nested loops - that is how I verified. However, I plugged in the limits just as you put them. My question is, how did you determine what to put in your formula? Is there more work you can show for your answer?