# MTG: Probability of drawing a card with enough mana to play it (part 2)

Tags: probability

This is a continuation of the [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994336/mtg-probability-of-drawing-a-card-with-enough-mana-to-play-it):

Let's assume we have the same scenario

- 12 White
- 13 Black
- 3 Spell Card
- 32 Other cards

Based on the answers in Part 1, I can now answer that question, in general. The problem arises, when a card has, in its cost, a colorless mana. This seems to have thrown a wrench in the whole plan. I have asked [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996129/probability-of-a-drawing-a-specific-suit-and-a-specific-color) in an effort to learn from a simpler example. However, I have failed to grasp that concept and apply it here.

So, now I'm stuck. How do you account for a mana that can be any one of the colors? Here it may help to work off a simple example (but I'm after the general solution most importantly):

Assume Spell Card costs 4 mana to play (1 of any color, 2 White and 1 Black). If I drew 10 cards, what is the probability that I draw at least 1 Spell card, 1 colorless mana, 2 White and 1 Black?

Comment: How do you calculate the probability of drawing ten cards and getting a heart, and four spades: two of which are numbers less than 5 and one of which is between five and ten?

Comment: Is that not just a re-branding of my question or am I missing something?